# Mysterious mistake in code while handling with dynamic datastructures

Tags: c++

I am a beginner in C++ and been searching the whole day for my mistake but I cant find it.
I want to create a dynamic data structure and add some elements in it. But my first way is not working and I can't find out why.

I have now 2 cases. One that works and one that fails. I know that I could use the second way and not to ask this question but I think I really didn't understand something important and I am sure that I will do the same mistake again.

So here the code:

```
struct a{
  int count;
  int value;
  a* first;
  a* next;
};
```

Failing Case (first way):

```
int main(){
  a alist = { 0, 12, NULL, NULL }; //init the first one
  alist.first = &alist;

  for (int i = 0; i < 20; i++){  //creat some dyn. linked structures    
    if (alist.next == NULL){
      alist.next = new a;
      alist.next->count = i;
      alist.next->first = alist.first;
      alist.next->next = NULL;
      alist.next->value = 12; //just a test value
      alist = *(alist.next);            
    }
  }

  alist = *(alist.first); //reset to start from the beginning 
  cout << "count of created Structs:" << endl;
  for (int i = 0; i < 20; i++){  //show count if structs exists
    if (alist.next != NULL){
      cout << "_" << i << endl;
      alist = *(alist.next);
    }
  }
  return 0;
}
```

Output:

```
count of created Structs:
```

Working Case:

```
int main(){
  a* alist = new a{ 0, 12, NULL, NULL }; //init the first one
  alist->first = alist;

  for (int i = 0; i < 20; i++){  //creat some dyn. linked structures    
    if (alist->next == NULL){
      alist->next = new a;
      alist->next->count = i;
      alist->next->value = 12; //just a test value
      alist->next->first = alist->first;
      alist->next->next = NULL;
      alist = alist->next;
    }
  }

  alist = alist->first; //reset to start from the beginning 
  cout << "count of created Structs:" << endl;
  for (int i = 0; i < 20; i++){  //show countnumber if structs exists
    if (alist->next != NULL){
      cout << "_" << i << endl;
      alist = (alist->next);
    }
  }
  return 0;
}
```

Output:

```
count of created Structs:
_0,_0,_1,_2,_3,..._19
```

Comment: You are overwriting alist.  Thus destroying the head node of the list.  Debug by starting with *one* node, make sure you can distinguish the nodes by giving them unique values.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The statement

```
alist = *(alist.next);
```

is overwriting your local object `alist` in each loop iteration with the `next` link in the list. In the last iteration, it's set with an object whose `next` is `NULL`.  Every object's `first` pointer is pointing to this local object that's being overwritten.  When you try to show the created structs, the first evaluation checking whether `next` is `NULL` will fail.

There is no overwriting in the second version because you're using pointer assignment instead of object copying.

Comment: OMG. Thx a lot. Now i see it too  :D                                                                  And thx to sanfor too..for correcting my bad english... im sry but thx for help :) (sry i still not found how to send you a pm :S... so i send it here)

Comment: Most people stick to advancing pointers through linked lists. It's just easier (and faster).